# Requests for touch icons from android

Tags: android, web-applications, request, favicon, embedded-browser

Does anyone know the logical flow and timing behind requests for apple-touch-icon.png by android apps that use an embedded webkit browser?

What I seem to be seeing (but am having trouble verifying) is that a GET request for the touch icon is made **before** the webpage itself. Perhaps this is by design so that users get some kind of feedback the page is loading before the bulky webpage is downloaded.

It's causing problems because my company has launched an application that sits behind a single sign-on solution - the SSO intercepts the first get request to the server and returns a login page instead. After the user's logged in, they are then redirected to the URL of the intercepted request.

What seems to be happening on android is that users are logging in, then getting redirected to the /apple-touch-icon.png instead of the page they were expecting...